# flow flags bad property access on number var but not number property

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following code, there is a var of type `Number`, and an object property of type `Number`. Trying to access an unknown property on both, flow reports an error only on the var.

```
var obj: {
    x: number,
    get: () => number
} = {
    x: 5,
    get() {
        return this.x && this.x.a.b.c;
    }
};

module.exports = function () {
    var y = 6,
        z = y.a.b.c;

    return z + obj.get();
};
```

The error is

```
z = y.a.b.c;
      ^ property `a`. Property not found in
z = y.a.b.c;
    ^ Number
```

Why doesn't it flag the same access on the object property?

Update: I just noticed that if I remove the type annotation from obj, flow *does* report the error in obj.get. No idea why that is.

Comment: I assume because `this.x` can change by external means.. but `y = 6`, on a line above it knows it can't change.  It knows it's going to be type Number, but it can't guarantee the same for a property..

Comment: Hm. obj isn't exported, so it also can't be changed. Also, isn't the point of type annotations to flag code that would violate the annotation? So the property should always be Number?

Comment: Using `this` in a case like this doesn't even make sense. What if someone did `obj.get.call(undefined)`? If you did `return obj.x && obj.x.a.b.c` it'd error fine I'm sure.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Not sure what you mean about not making sense. All js objects work like this. You can invoke ```.call(undefined)``` on any method, e.g. ```[].entries.call(undefined)```. How is my example different than every other js object?